# How to we use the control inside RadGrid edit field as Select Control parameter Control id

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, telerik, sqldatasource

I had a textbox control inside radgrid edit template, I want to use it as `sqldatasource` select parameter `ControlID` .

```
<SelectParameters>
   <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
</SelectParameters>
```